# THREE.js SpriteMaterial glow texture hiding edges

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm adding a SpriteMaterial glow texture to some THREE.js nodes and there are some issues with how it is being drawn over edges.  From some angles it works fine but from others the edges are not visible through the texture even though it is set to transparent.  The circled areas in the image below highlight the problems.

[image]

Here is the code I use to create the SpriteMaterial:

```
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/glow2.png'), color: color, transparent: true, side: THREE.FrontSide, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending });
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
sprite.scale.set(30, 30, 1.0);
```

Is this an issue with the texture png and if so, how can I create an image for a texture that won't produce these types of artifacts?  If it's not an image problem, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you do a working snippet so we can properly consider the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add depthWrite:false to your SpriteMaterial params.